# Trouble with learning how to use GNU Autotools to package my program

Tags: c, linux, gnu, autotools

I am attepting to use GNU Autotools for the first time to package my C program called MyShell. I have tried twice but have failed both times. I followed [this simple tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Creating-amhello.html#Creating-amhello), but where my program differs and what is causing the problem (I think) is that there is 1 `.h` file and 5 `.c` files, whereas this tutorial uses just a single `.c` file.

Here is the file structure of my program:

**MyShell/**

- README
- src/

**src/**

- CommandExecutor.c
- CommandReader.c
- ForkLauncher.c
- Main.c
- MyShell.h
- MyShellLoop.c

Any guidance on how to write the Makefile.am files, the configure.ac file, etc. would be much appreciated, or else any more detailed tutorial on using Autotools for a more complex program.

**EDIT**

These are the files I used:

**MyShell/src/Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = MyShell
MyShell_SOURCES = Main.c
```

**MyShell/Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS = src
dist_doc_DATA = README
```

**MyShell/configure.ac**

```
AC_INIT([MyShell], [1.0], [<my email address>])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
 Makefile
 src/Makefile
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

In the tutorial I have linked, the configure.ac file has the line

```
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
```

Should I have replaced `config.h` with `MyShell.h`?

Comment: 'Tis complex.  Are you adapting your program so it compiles on multiple different system types?  If so, you need a separate `config.h` file that will be generated by the `configure` script on the clients machine, and the AutoTools will create the configure script (etc) from the information you specify.  If you don't need to configure your program, using AutoTools is probably over-kill.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In the future I would like it to run on different systems, but for now it only needs to be run in Linux. It is an assignment and we were are asked to use Autotools to package it, or else "write your own Makefile and create a tar.gz maually".

Comment: Between the two, I'd take the manually written makefile every time — it isn't that hard (though it isn't entirely trivial to do it cleanly).  However, exercises are exercises and provide a learning experience.  I have a couple of autoconfiscated programs, one using `automake` too — but I did the autoconfiscation a long time ago (2007 by the looks of the revision histories).  I've had plenty of time to forget the details (and recover from the wounds inflicted on me by the system).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyShell_SOURCES = Main.c
```

This seems to be wrong. You need to list all source files, [including header files](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-Sources.html#Program-Sources).

> Should I have replaced `config.h` with `MyShell.h`?

No. `config.h` should be generated by the `configure` script from a `config.h.in` file. "How" can be pretty [complex](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.66/html_node/Configuration-Headers.html#Configuration-Headers).

Comment: ok makes sense, just a comma separated list? Also, I need to submit this as a college assignment where the name of the program has to be in the format of xxxx_xxxx. Can I just replace any 'MyShell' with 'xxxx_xxxx' in the Makefiles and configure file? Or will this cause a problem at `xxxx_xxxx_Sources = MyShell.h, Main.c ...`?

Comment: AFAIK this should be no problem.

Comment: Wait, not *comma separated* ... **whitespace separated** .. like in the link I posted.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have another go now